# UIScrollView could not scroll after adding subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scrollbar

I happened this problem, I added a scrollview horizontally and a `UITextview` to a scrollview, but in the simulator the view could not scroll well.

My question is: How to set the contentsize to make it scroll?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.title  = scenery.name;
    mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

    self.imagePaths = [scenery imagePaths];
    imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH, 240)];
    imageScrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    imageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    imageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self AddImgsToScrollView];
    self.currentPage = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimer:)  userInfo:nil  repeats: YES];

    [mainScrollView addSubview:imageScrollView];

    //Introduction Text View
    introView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    introView.text = scenery.introduction;
    introView.editable = NO;
    introView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    [introView setScrollEnabled:NO];

    CGSize textViewSize = [introView.text sizeWithFont:introView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH-20, FLT_MAX)];


    CGRect newFrame = introView.frame;
    newFrame.size = textViewSize;
    newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(10,245);
    introView.frame = newFrame;
    [mainScrollView addSubview:introView];

    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView *view in mainScrollView.subviews){
      if (scrollViewHeight < view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height) scrollViewHeight = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height;
}
    newFrame = mainScrollView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(WIDTH, scrollViewHeight);
    mainScrollView.frame = newFrame;
    NSLog(@"%f/%f", scrollViewHeight,textViewSize.height);

   [mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH, scrollViewHeight)];

   [self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];

}
```

Comment: Why u are making it complex by adding scroll view into scroll view and another scroll view ..... what u need give clear specification?
 How  you want your view looks like????

Comment: [mainScrollView addSubview:imageScrollView]; why you add scrollview inside another scrollview

Comment: Check user interaction for view is set to NO. So that touch event will be sent to scrollview.

Comment: imageScrollView is a horizontally scrollview and would display serval images like slideshow, its width would somehow larger. The height of Image and TextView would exceed screen height, so I want to add scrollview to let users can scroll to view content.

Comment: If your textview width is same or greater than your mainscrollview width, so when you click your textview, it will be the first listener and it will become first responder and keyboard will appear.The event will not be sent to mainscrollview.Since your textview width depend upon text width: newFrame.size = textViewSize;

Comment: textview width is equal mainscrollview, and the textview is **not editable** but imageScrollView isn't. is there any ways to implement the function I want. top is an image slideshow, and below is a uitextview, and show a long text with scrollbar **not the uitextview scrollbar, it's screen scrollbar**.

Comment: Not sure but try by providing userInteraction NO for uitextview.

Comment: Thanks Nuzhat. UserInteraction set to No had no effect, if I increase the mainScrollView height, the scrollbar would appear, but not precise, still have textview content clip or leave a blank in the bottom.

Comment: Can you post some default view image of how exactly you want your view?

Comment: @NuzhatZari [the view I want](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lIQWT.png) here  u go.

Comment: It is not showing anything.

Comment: @NuzhatZari Sorry, Stackoverflow seems could not show images upload in post, please check this out: http://thumbsnap.com/NqrauzQV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I got the answer.

```
CGRect newFrame = introView.frame;
newFrame.size = textViewSize;
newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(10,245);
introView.frame = newFrame;
[mainScrollView addSubview:introView];

CGFloat scrollViewHeight = introView.contentSize.height + imageScrollView.contentSize.height + 64;
newFrame = mainScrollView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(WIDTH, 480);
newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
mainScrollView.frame = newFrame;

[mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH, scrollViewHeight)];
```

**1. Set the mainScrollView frame as the height of screen.**

**2. And then use setContentSize to set the height of all subviews.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following . this is working code for me .

```
            int scrollWidth=60;
            for (int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
            {
                UIImageView *imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollWidth,8,50,40)];
                imageView1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                imageView1.backgroundColor=[array objectAtIndex:i];
                [scrollView addSubview:imageView1];
                scrollWidth=scrollWidth+80;
            }

            [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, 30)];
```

Also check in xib whether user interaction and scrolling in enable or not .

Comment: In the above mentioned code for me, it always adds the last view for me from the loop.Could you tell me where did you add this code in viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad ?

Comment: cant tell what is exact issue without knowing your code . But I guess the issue may be with the scrollview content size , Make sure your setting it right , [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, 30)];

Comment: thanks for the answer but I found out the reason why it was the issue. I was not initializing the views for each loop.